# How to overlap graphs in the asp:Chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph

I'm trying to make a Pareto chart using asp:Chart. It's basically a chart composed of a bar and a line graph. Now when I try to put the two in the same ChartArea, it gives me an error saying I can't put two different Series in the same ChartArea.

I need right y-axis to be price of each Bar element and the left y-axis to be a percentage that corresponds to the line graph.

My code so far:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" onload="Chart1_Load" Width="847px" Height="422px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Bar" YValueType="Double">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Line" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>

    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I have values inserted in the Bar graph in the underlying C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing both of your asp series tags in the same Series container tag:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" onload="Chart1_Load" Width="847px" Height="422px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Bar" YValueType="Double">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Line" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>

    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```